# How to reuse Django app in same project by dynamically loading modules in urls and views

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.7

I have almost three instances of the same app and I try to replace my copy paste-code with something more reusable. I have solved the models by using abstact models, looking like this:

```
# apps.base.myapp.models
class MyAppBase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# apps.site_v1.myapp.models
class MyApp(MyAppBase):
    pass

# apps.site_v2.myapp
class MyApp(MyAppBase):
    pass
```

For the apps in *site_v1* and *site_v2*  I had to add an appconfig, as I couldn't use the same names for two apps:

```
# apps.site_v1.myapp.apps
class CustomAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.site_v1.myapp.apps'
    label = 'site_v1_myapp'

# apps.site_v2.myapp.apps
class CustomAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.site_v2.myapp.apps'
    label = 'site_v2_myapp'
```

I want to have the following in my *urls.py* and *views.py* in my two versions of the site (and be able to change them if I want):

```
# apps.site_v1.myapp.views and apps.site_v2.myapp.views
from apps.base.myapp.views import *

# apps.site_v1.myapp.urls and apps.site_v2.myapp.urls
from apps.base.myapp.urls import *
```

My problem, though, is how I dynamically can set up generic *urls.py* and *views.py* in *apps.base.myapp* to support this config?

```
# apps.base.myapp.urls
views = ??? # Import dynamically, depending on whether I'm on site_v1 or site_v2

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.MyView.as_view(), name='index'),
)
```

I have elaborated a bit on the *views.py*, and, as I have /v1/ or /v2/ in the URL, I'm able to fetch whether I'm using v1 or v2 in a view and load the correct model. But I can't find any way on how to get this information in the *urls.py* so I can load the correct module.

In my main *urls.py* for I have specified the versions also:

```
# project.urls
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^site_v1/', include('urls_site_v1', namespace='site_v1', app_name='cur_site')),
    url(r'^site_v2/', include('urls_site_v2', namespace='site_v2', app_name='cur_site')),
)
```

So if I can access what namespace is used, or which app is being used in some way, I think it could solve the problem.

Having only one app and some variable defining which instance it is is not an option, as I want be able to modify them separately and have them in different databases.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but have you had a look at django's sites framework (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/)? It seems like that is what you need.